# Gradient of a softmax applied on a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, partial-derivative, gradient-descent

I am trying to calculate the softmax gradient:
$$p_j=[f(\vec{x})]_j = \frac{e^{W_jx+b_j}}{\sum_k e^{W_kx+b_k}}$$
With the cross-entropy error:
$$L = -\sum_j y_j \log p_j$$
Using [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945871/derivative-of-softmax-loss-function) I get that
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial o_i} = p_i - y_i$$
Where $o_i=W_ix+b_i$

So, by applying the chain rule I get to:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial b_i}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial o_i}\frac{\partial o_i}{\partial b_i} = (p_i - y_i)1=p_i - y_i$$
Which makes sense (dimensionality wise)
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial W_i}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial o_i}\frac{\partial o_i}{\partial W_i} = (p_i - y_i)\vec{x}$$
**Which has a dimensionality mismatch**

(for example if dimensions are $W_{3\times 4},\vec{b}_4,\vec{x}_3$)

What am I doing wrong ? and what is the correct gradient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dimension mismatch appears when you are using the chain rule. In case of taking the derivative with respect to $W_i$ (which denotes the $i$-th row of $W$, right?), we have maps 
$$ W_i \in \mathbf R^{1 \times k} \mapsto o_i = W_ix+b_i \in \mathbf R \mapsto L \in \mathbf R $$
hence a function $\mathbf R^{1 \times k} \to \mathbf R$, therefore the derivative is a map 
$$ \mathbf R^{1 \times k} \to L(\mathbf R^{1 \times k}, \mathbf R)$$
which assigns to each point $W_i \in \mathbf R^{1 \times k}$ a linear map $\mathbf R^{1 \times k} \to \mathbf R$. The chain rule tells us that for $h \in \mathbf R^{1 \times k}$, we have
$$ \def\pd#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\pd{L}{W_i}h = \pd{L}{o_i}\cdot \pd{o_i}{W_i}h $$
Now, as $W_i \mapsto o_i$ is affine, the derivative at any point equals the linear part, that is 
$$ \pd{o_i}{W_i} = hx, \qquad h \in \mathbf R^{1 \times k}  $$
Therefore 
$$ \pd L{W_i}h = (p_i - y_i)hx $$
that is $\pd{L}{W_i}$ is the linear map 
$$ \mathbf R^{1 \times k} \ni h \mapsto (p_i - y_i)hx $$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, i fail to comprehend, what is $h$ ?

Comment: By the very definition, a derivative of a function $f \colon \mathbf R^{1 \times k} \to \mathbf R$ (which is $W_i \mapsto L$), is a function $f'\colon \mathbf R^{1 \times k} \to L(\mathbf R^{1 \times k}, \mathbf R)$, that is, for any $W_i \in \mathbf R^{1 \times k}$, we have a linear map 
$$ f'(W_i) \colon \mathbf R^{1 \times k} \to \mathbf R$$
the argument of which is usually called $h$.

Answer (score 4):

You can use differentials to tackle the problem.

Define the auxiliary variables
$$\eqalign {
  o &= Wx+b \cr
  e &= \exp(o) \cr
  p &= \frac{e}{1:e} \cr
}$$
with their corresponding differentials
$$\eqalign {
 do &= dW\,x + db \cr
 de &= e\odot do \cr
 dp &= \frac{de}{1:e} - \frac{e(1:de)}{(1:e)^2} \,\,\,\,=\,\, (P-pp^T)\,do \cr
}$$where : denotes the double-dot (aka Frobenius) product, and $\odot$ denotes the element-wise (aka Hadamard) product, and $P = \operatorname{Diag}(p)$.

Now substitute these into the cross-entropy function, and find its differential
$$\eqalign {
  L &= -y:\log(p) \cr\cr
 dL &= -y:d\log(p) \cr
    &= -y:P^{-1}dp \cr
    &= -y:P^{-1}(P-pp^T)\,do \cr
    &= -y:(I-1p^T)\,do \cr
    &= (p1^T-I)y:(dW\,x + db) \cr
    &= (p1^T-I)yx^T:dW + (p1^T-I)y:db \cr\cr
}$$
Setting $db=0$ yields the gradient wrt $W$
$$\eqalign {
\frac{\partial L}{\partial W} &= (p1^T-I)yx^T \cr
  &= (p-y)x^T \cr
}$$
while setting $dW=0$ yields the gradient wrt $b$
$$\eqalign {
\frac{\partial L}{\partial b} &= (p1^T-I)y \cr
  &= p-y \cr
}$$
Note that in the above derivation, the $\log$ and $\exp$ functions are applied element-wise to their vector arguments.

Based on your expected results, you appear to use an unstated constraint that $1^Ty=1$, which I have used to simplify the final results.