# Derivative of Softmax loss function issue

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, machine-learning

I am trying to use chain rule in derviating the loss for the Softmax function, but i stuck. In this [great answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945871/derivative-of-softmax-loss-function?newreg=3d36b9ccf99b4532823133246c76693b):
I can't realize, why the log(p_k) derivative with respect to o is 1/p_k but not 1/(p_k * ln(10))?

Comment: In the post you've referenced, the natural logarithm is being used, so you don't need the conversion factor for a base-10 log.  Keep in mind that in many (most?) branches of applied math and science, the natural logarithm is denote as $\log(x)$.  It's mainly in undergraduate courses where the ${\rm ln}(x)$ notaton is encountered.

Comment: @greg, thanks a lot!