# Softmax function derivative - a couple of doubts

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, logistic-regression

Given, the SoftMax function:

\begin{equation}
p_j = \frac{e^{o_j}}{\sum_k e^{o_k}}
\end{equation}
which is posted here:
[Derivative of Softmax loss function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945871/derivative-of-softmax-loss-function)

The following are it's derivatives, as posted in the link:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial o_i} = p_i(1 - p_i),\quad i = j
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p_j}{\partial o_i} = -p_i p_j,\quad i \neq j.
\end{equation}

I just wanted to know HOW we arrived at these derivatives, and have been scratching my head for hours!
Another thing I can't understand, along similar lines is how we arrive at this..:

\begin{equation}1+\sum_{j=1}^{M-1}\exp{\{\eta_{j}\}}={\sum_{j=1}^M\exp{\{\eta_{j}\}}}\end{equation}

Much appreciate any answers, thank you!

Comment: You just need to apply $\frac{d(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})}{dx} = \frac{f'g-g'f}{g^2}$.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you.