# Derivative of Softmax loss function with $\text{one}_\text{hot}(y)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, machine-learning

Given the following:

$h=g\left(w_1\cdot x+b_1\right)$

$ z=w_2\cdot h+b_2$

$y_\text{hat} = \mbox{softmax}\left(z\right)$

$\mbox{Loss}\left(y,y_\text{hat}\right)=-\sum \mbox{onehot}\left(y\right)\cdot \log\left(y_\text{hat}\right)$

How can we derivate the loss function: $\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}$?

Comment: What is $\operatorname{softmax}(z)$ and $onehot$? Make your OP clear by adding the meaning of your notation, otherwise your question will be doomed to be closed and forgotten.

Comment: Functions have domains and codomains.

Comment: What have you yourself attempted?  What is the source of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here [softmax](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789676/derivative-of-softmax-loss-function-with-temperature-t/4357826#4357826), you will see that with your notations
$$
\frac{\partial \mathrm{Loss}}{\partial \mathbf{z}}
= \mathbf{y}_\mathrm{hat} - \mathrm{onehot}(y)
$$
which is particularly simple...