# RNN Back propagation proof

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, machine-learning

Chapter 10 of the [Deep Learning book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) has

> $$
> \begin{align}
> a^{(t)} &= b + Wh^{(t-1)} + Ux^{(t)} \\
> h^{(t)} &= \tanh(a^{(t)})\\
> o^{(t)} &= c + Vh^{(t)}\\
> \hat{y}^{(t)} &= \text{softmax}(o^{(t)})\\ \\
> L &= \sum_t L^{(t)}\\
> &= -\sum_t \log{p_{\text{model}}(y^{(t)}\ |\ x^{(1)},\dots,x^{(t)})}
> \end{align}
> $$
> where $p_{\text{model}}(y^{(t)}\ |\ x^{(1)},\dots,x^{(t)})$ is given by reading the entry for $y^{(t)}$ from the model's output vector $\hat{y}^{(t)}$.
> ...
> $$
> \frac{\partial L}{\partial L^{(t)}}=1\\
> (\nabla_{\pmb{o}^{(t)}}L)_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial L^{(t)}}\frac{\partial L^{(t)}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}} = \hat{y}_i^{(t)} - \pmb{1}_{i=y^{(t)}}
> $$

I got $\frac{\partial L^{(t)}}{\partial o_i^{(t)}} = \hat{y}_i^{(t)} - y_i^{(t)}$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/945918/1016494). But how do we get the result in the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both writing are identical.

In vector form, you can write
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{o}} = \mathrm{softmax}(\mathbf{o})-\mathbf{y}
$$
where vector $\mathbf{y}$ is null everywhere except at the position that indicates the class.
For instance $y(2)=1$ if we are dealing with an example from the second class...

Comment: But the book uses $\pmb{1}_{i=y^{(t)}}$ (appears to be a vector) even for the $i^{th}$ component of gradient, as cited in the question. Is that incorrect?

Comment: no it is not a vector. In the Goodfellow's book, this term is 1 if y=i (if the class of the example is i) or 0 otherwise. This is one-hot encoding and it is how I defined the vector $\mathbf{y}$.